# How to create a CASE WHEN by checking the time of a column

Tags: postgresql

I have a column named "create_date" in a table which has datetime mentioned in UTC.

**Actual:**

```
|create_date|

2019-07-30 14:52:38.0  
2019-07-29 09:49:51.0  
2019-07-30 04:27:56.0  
2019-08-02 16:07:44.0  
2019-08-05 02:30:12.0  
2019-08-03 20:44:14.0
```

I would like create another column using CASE WHEN with condition as time between '02:30:00.0' and '14:30:00.0' as "India" and ELSE as "Not India"

**Expected:**

```
|create_date|City|

2019-07-30 14:52:38.0 | Not India  
2019-07-29 09:49:51.0 | India  
2019-07-30 04:27:56.0 | India  
2019-08-02 16:07:44.0 | Not India  
2019-08-05 02:30:12.0 | India  
2019-08-03 20:44:14.0 | Not India
```

I've tried executing the below query but had no luck

```
SELECT create_date,      
CASE WHEN (to_char(create_date, 'HH:MI:SS') BETWEEN '02:30:00' AND '14:30:00') THEN    'India'  
ELSE 'Not India'  
END AS "City"  
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `::time` cast:

```
SELECT
    create_date,
    CASE WHEN create_date::time BETWEEN '02:30:00.0' AND '14:30:00.0'
         THEN 'India' ELSE 'Not India' END AS City
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `HH24` format string rather than `HH` to get the hours in 24-hour clock format.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT create_date,      
CASE WHEN (to_char(create_date, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '02:30:00' AND '14:30:00') THEN    'India'  
ELSE 'Not India'  
END AS "City"  
FROM TABLE_NAME
```